# Opencv meters reprojectImageTo3D values under 0, is right?

Tags: opencv, computer-vision

i am using opencv to take measurements in meters from point A to point B with the formula of the distance between points in 3d in the real world.
sqrt( (Bx - Ax)² + (By - Ay)² + (Bz - Az)² )
I made the calibration code, after I use the reprojectImageTo3D (point cloud) function providing the the calibration matrix and the disparity map to get the measurements in meters.
Except that the reproject3d function gives me an array with negative values on both the x axis and the z axis. Is it correct that the function returns negative values?
If not, what did I do wrong to get measurements in meters?

Comment: yes. -- what do you think should the signs of the values be along the x axis, on the left vs right half of the space in front of the camera?

Comment: I think they must be values above zero because the distance in meters from the cameras

Comment: no. you're talking about Z. I'm asking about X (and Y). can you picture in your mind a 3D space with coordinate axes?

Comment: I expect the value 0 from the far left and the value 25 meters on the far right.
while for y I expect the value +25 meters from the highest point and 0 meters in the lower value.
But this is not a well-defined logical sense.
So I imagine that the values on the left are with the minus (-2.5 meters), while those on the right (+ 3.7 meters) with the plus (the same for y) with respect to the center. Right? What would the center be?

Comment: wrong expectations. coordinates dead ahead are (0, 0, z) for some positive z. coordinates in the left half are (x, y, z) with negative x, right half it's positive x. bottom half, +y, top half -y. -- remember, it's not angles. points in space don't care what your field of view is. you should learn about "right-handed" coordinate systems. that's what OpenCV uses, and I've already stated which axis goes where in my first comment.

Comment: so is it right that there are negative values?

Comment: which is the half for x and for y? how do i find the half value in 3D space?

Comment: I believe I stated that in exceeding detail. -- what is "half value"? are you asking where the optical axis lies? please learn about the "pinhole" camera model. Stack Overflow is not a tutoring service nor does it replace books and lectures and youtube tutorials. if you're dealing with this subject matter, you should be able to gain knowledge on your own, and this stuff is fundamental.